# Laravel - Blade - <!-- __BLOCK__ --> <!-- __ENDBLOCK__ -->

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

when I use in Blade @if, @foreach etc. Laravel add extra

`<!-- _ BLOCK _ --> <!-- _ ENDBLOCK -->`

lines.
How can I get rid of this. This was never happed before.

Laravel 10 + Livewire 3 (latest versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's from livewire. In the docs folder in the livewire repository, there is a readme file, called morph.md (https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/main/docs/morph.md#injecting-morph-markers)

Those are markers used by livewire as a guide to detect the difference between a change and an addition.

Per doc you can disable them by going into the configuration in your application's `config/livewire.php` and use:

```
'inject_morph_markers' => false,
```

This should resolve your issue, but I would recommend to leave it on, as it is extremly beneficial to livewire applications.

Comment: Thanks. I have readed all docs and I will leave this markers in code.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Morph Markers**

> Livewire intelligently "morphs" existing HTML into the newly rendered HTML after each update. To make this process more reliable, Livewire injects "markers" into the rendered Blade surrounding @if, @class & @foreach.

*(config/livewire.php)*

It is not recommended to change this value because Livewire 3 natively uses and most likely needs it.

**@if, @class, @foreach** will be surrounded by those markers but you won't see them unless you are using them inside **input or textarea** Elements:

```
<textarea>@if($some_Value) {{$some_value}} @endif</textarea>
```

**Input Elements** will display HTML-Comments.

Try to use:

```
{{$some_value}}
```

instead.

If you do need more complex output, separate it from the output:

```
@php
   // Some Process like if, foreach
   // manipulates a $value
@endphp
```

Which you can use in your desired Element:

```
<textarea>{{$value}}</textarea>
```

...to avoid **@foreach, @if**

But please remember that Input Elements in **Livewire 3** most likely are combined with **wire:model** Attributes:

```
// Single public value
<textarea wire:model="some_value"></textarea>

// Or an array value
<textarea wire:model="array.some_value"></textarea>

// Or a model property
<textarea wire:model="model.some_value"></textarea>
```